# CheckedListBox editing/adding

Tags: c#, user-interface, checkedlistbox

I have this Checked List Box, `listPlayers`. I would like to have it add (or remove) names when asked. These names are in `string` input, naturally.

Here is the code in question:

```
namespace TakoBot
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Form1 MainForm { get; private set; }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MainForm = new Form1();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        public static void OnMessage(object sender, PlayerIOClient.Message m)
        {
            if (m.Type == "add")
            {
                NamesInt[m.GetString(1)] = m.GetInt(0);
                NamesString[m.GetInt(0)] = m.GetString(1);
                Program.MainForm.listPlayers.Add("PlayersName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon calling the action `Form1.listPlayers.Add("PlayersName");`, we get the error:

```
"'MyProgram.Form1.listPlayers' is inaccessible due to its protection level"
```

..Okay, my error-handling skills aren't the best. Like I said, everything is `public`.

If I'm using entirely wrong actions, don't hesitate to show me correct ones.

Comment: Post your actual code in this case.

Comment: In your code you are creating two instances of a Form1 class, but only one is ever shown or made active.  What is calling OnMessage and why is it a static method?  You should attempt to place it as a non-static method in your Form1 class.  From within your Form1 class, you should be able to access listPlayers directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form1` is a type, not an instance.

In your `Program` do something like this

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form1 MainForm { get; private set; }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the form like this (`listPlayers` must be public)

```
Program.MainForm.listPlayers.Add("PlayersName");
```

---

As an alternative, you could expose the player list as a static property in `Form1`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static CheckedListBox PlayerList { get; private set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayerList = listPlayers;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you can access it like

```
Form1.PlayerList.Add("PlayersName");
```

because it is static, i.e. `PlayerList` belongs to the type (class) `Form1`, not to an instance (object) of `Form1`. This works only if you have only one instance of `Form1` open at any time.

---

Given

```
class MyClass
{
    public static string S;
    public string I;
}
```

You can do this

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
MyClass b = new MyClass();

a.I = "Hello";
MyClass.S = "One";

b.I = "World";
MyClass.S = "Two";
```

The static variable `MyClass.S` can have only one value at a given time. It will be `"Two"` at the end of this code.

The instance variable `I` can have a different value in each instance (`a`, `b`). At the end of this code `a.I` will be `"Hello"` and `b.I` will be `"World"`.

Comment: Well `listPlayers` is declared as private. In the properties window you can set the `Modifiers` property (found in category `Design`) of `listPlayers` to `Public`. `private` members are only visible inside of a class. See [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) on MSDN.